# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError returns when trying to create a stateless session to the Rules Execution Server

Tags: jrules

I am using Ilog JRules Studio 7.1.1 for the rules development. I am using JUnit test cases to test the developed rules.
When i am trying to create a stateless session to the RES, it's returning with the below error.

IlrStatelessSession session = factory.createStatelessSession();

Anyone is having any idea?

java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ilog/rules/res/decisionservice/plugin/IlrWsdlGenerationInteractionSpec.FUNCTION_NAME_BACKPORT_GENERATE_WSDL
    at ilog.rules.res.decisionservice.plugin.IlrWsdlGeneratorInteractionExtension.getSupportedFunctionNames(IlrWsdlGeneratorInteractionExtension.java:418)
    at ilog.rules.res.xu.plugin.impl.IlrPluginManager.createPlugins(IlrPluginManager.java:222)
    at ilog.rules.res.xu.plugin.impl.IlrPluginManager.changePlugins(IlrPluginManager.java:173)
    at ilog.rules.res.xu.plugin.impl.IlrPluginManager.start(IlrPluginManager.java:135)
    at ilog.rules.res.xu.spi.IlrManagedXUConnectionFactory.createConnectionFactory(IlrManagedXUConnectionFactory.java:648)
    at ilog.rules.res.xu.spi.IlrManagedXUConnectionFactory.createConnectionFactory(IlrManagedXUConnectionFactory.java:668)
    at ilog.rules.res.session.util.IlrJ2SEConnectionFactoryFinder.findConnectionFactory(IlrJ2SEConnectionFactoryFinder.java:23)
    at ilog.rules.res.session.IlrJ2SESessionFactory.createClientFactory(IlrJ2SESessionFactory.java:93)
    at ilog.rules.res.session.IlrJ2SESessionFactory.getClientFactory(IlrJ2SESessionFactory.java:129)
    at ilog.rules.res.session.IlrJ2SESessionFactory.createStatelessSession(IlrJ2SESessionFactory.java:62)

Regards,
Hari

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do with the session.
JRules is crashing because it is not able to generate the WSDL, meaning there is something wrong with your project at first.
Try to run it locally first.
The thing is a web service is automatically provided if the XOM is based on XSD
There is an error somewhere in your project. If you use XSD (which I guess) then have a look to your rule project.
If you use JAVA XOM then there is an error in your web service server (which I doubt) because I cannot see why JRules would complain for your own code.
Verify your in/output parameters
Make it simple first then complicate the process.
If simple then redeploy...

Hope it helps

Comment: I was tried to use Jrules 7.0.0 Execution server jars in Jrules studio 7.1.1 environment. That was the mistake. I completed reinstalled the version 7.0.0 for my development. Thanks for your information Damien